# Retain class independence or avoid type checking

Tags: java, optimization, typechecking

I'm still a beginner in java, but I try to write good code (obj oriented). However, I'm having a problem with the method `removeFromWorld`. I several approaches, but whatever I do I seem to break a "rule" of good programming practice.

I tried it with type-checking:

```
    public class World{
        private Set setGiraffes;
        public void removeFromWorld(Animal animal){
            if (isGiraffe(animal))
                setGiraffes.remove((Giraffe) animal)
            else if (isZebra(animal)){...}
        else if ...
        }
    }
    public abstract class Animal{..}

    public class Giraffe extends Animal{..}
```

but heard that was a bad idea since it's impossible to add a new animal without changing existing methods. I considered moving `removeFromWorld` to Animal and overwriting it in each subclass, but since it's World using the sets, that seemed bad as well

I'm quite at a loss as for what would be an "elegant"/good solution.

Comment: First things to do: fix your indentation to improve readability, follow Java naming conventions, and use generics. Next: explain *why* you want to have a set just of giraffes, and one of zebras etc. What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation and naming, not exactly sure what  you mean by generics. I needed those sets to iterate over them and check for possible interactions (check with all other giraffes wheter they have entered the territory of the that one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, this style of programming kills maintainability of your code right away.

There are two simple ways of handling this - implementing a [*visitor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), and defining a `Map` based on `Class<T>`.

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
interface Visitor {
    void visitGiraffe(Giraffe g);
    void visitZebra(Zebra z);
}
abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void accept(Visitor v);
}
class Giraffe extends Animal {
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visitGiraffe(this);
    }
}
class Zebra extends Animal {
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visitZebra(this);
    }
}
```

With this structure in hand, you can write your remover as follows:

```
void removeFromWorld(Animal a) {
    a.accept(new Visitor() {
        public void visitGiraffe(Giraffe g) {
            setOfGiraffes.remove(g);
        }
        public void visitZebra(Zebra z) {
            setOfZebras.remove(z);
        }
    });
}
```

The second relies on the ability of Java objects to produce their `Class`. Now instead of defining

```
Set<Giraffe> setOfGiraffes = ...
Set<Zebra> setOfZebras = ...
```

you can define

```
Map<Class,Set<Animal>> setOfAnimalByClass = ...
```

To access giraffes, you would do

```
setOfAnimalByClass.get(Giraffe.class).add(new Giraffe());
```

and so on. Then you can implement `removeFromWorld` like this:

```
void removeFromWorld(Animal a) {
    a.accept(new Visitor() {
        setOfAnimals.get(a.getClass()).remove(a);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return a set of the type Set<Giraffe>, using this map?  (this is strictly speaking a question within a question I think, so if it's against the rules, just notify me and i'll remove the comment and ask it as a standalone question)

Comment: @Wouter Although this is a separate question, there's little point in asking it separately, because it would be a duplicate. In Java, generics are implemented through *type erasure*, meaning that `Set<Giraffe>` would be indistinguishable from `Set<Animal>` once it is placed inside the `Map`. You wouldn't be able to derive any benefits from generics if you place untyped sets inside the `Map`, though.

Comment: So i'll have to iterate through the set, parse the elements and add them to a new Set? (i'm working inside an interface which i can't change)

Comment: @Wouter You can cast the set of animals to a set of giraffes, and silence the warning. The compiler cannot check it for you, but if you know how you construct the set, there is no harm in casting the set as a whole, because the underlying type is the same regardless of the generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all animals hava a `removeFromWorld` method but each child has a different version then the elegant solution is to make `Animal` an abstract class and `removeFromWorld` an abstract method. That way any class that extends `Animal` has to have its own `removeFromWorld` method (and cannot accidently use the generic Animal one). Whether you actually want to do that or not though will depend on your actual application

Comment: I don't know why you accepted the other answer; this one is much easier and does what you want to do.  Put more succintly: make an Animal abstract class with an empty removeFromWorld(), then implement removeFromWorld() in a subclass for each animal.

Comment: Creating a map by class seemed a handier solution, since I could more easily access all the different sets at once if I wanted to. I also think it would make more sense to keep the method in removeFromWorld in world (as I stated in my question). But thanks for pointing it out, I may need to reconsider if using the map (or Visitor) turns out to be a pain.

Comment: @Wouter I'm inclined to agree. My answer achieves moving removeFromWorld into the Animal class in an elegant mannor. However for your application I think the second of dasblinkenlight's answers is the most appropriate